# VB.NET Adding a control and set parent

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to dynamically add a usercontrol (this works fine) and then set it's parent (this does not work fine).

My current code is:

```
    ucGrid1 = New ucGrid
    ucGrid.Parent = Me.TableLayoutPanel1'the ".Parent" property is not available
    ucGrid1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is `ucGrid`? Is that a control that inherits from `System.Windows.Winforms.Control`?

Comment: @icemanind Yepp, it is / does.

Comment: Oh wow, when I added Public Class ucGrid : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control to my control, the .Parent function was visible! Could you therefore make your reply the answer? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `ucGrid` is a control that inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. Specifically add the namespace if needed.